# Setting delegate for NSSplitView results in error

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I created a ViewController, together with an xib file. 
So the ViewController is the File's owner. 
To the header file I added the NSSplitViewDelegate

```
@interface ResultViewController : NSViewController <NSSplitViewDelegate>
```

In the interface builder I set the delegate of the splitview to the files owner class. 
But if I try to load the view it results in the following error:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=13, adress=0x0)

During the compile process no warnings or error appears.

I open the view, using the following way:

```
ResultViewController *newView = [[ResultViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultViewController" bundle:nil];
[[self.windowIbject animator] setContentView: newView.view];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try retaining your `newView` controller. You could add a property to the interface of the class where you init it:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ResultViewController *newView;
```

Then where you init it add:

```
self.newView = newView;
```

Comment: thanks that works. So just for my understanding: If I haven't the property the class was already released, when the delegate try to access it.

Comment: Yes. Because delegates are normally (there are some exceptions to this) weak referenced, there was no strong reference left to your view controller, so ARC released it.